# Windows XP Print Server (share printer without file and printer sharing)

Tags: windows

is there possibility to make PrintServer of a WinXP Pro machine. I need to make it possibile without File And Printer Sharing. And also without using those small cheap hardware print servers.
 I searched google, but cannot find anything except "raw print server" a small app that doesnt work :). Any help is appriciated.

Comment: You want to printer share without actually allowing printer sharing, is there some reason for this requirement?

Answer (score 2):

I frequently use the "Print Services for Unix" Windows XP optional feature (listed under "Other Network File and Print Services" to allow Windows XP machines to export locally-attached printers as LPR queues. It works very well for me, and has been more reliable than using "File and Print Sharing for Microsoft Networks" to create queues on print server computers which send jobs to printers attached to client computers.

If you're going to be sending jobs from the "Standard TCP/IP Port" implementation on other Windows machines be sure to enable the "LPR Byte Counting" option on the client "Standard TCP/IP Port" or you'll find that jobs don't print on the "server" machine.

Comment: You know, I never realized that was there? I'm going to have to pay more attention to print services.

Comment: AErnieTheGeek: Using this feature is SOP for me, now, when the Customer wants to "share" printers from clients. I create a queue on their server computer that the users actually send print jobs to and "point" that queue at the LPR port being hosted by the client computer. I get all the benefits of a server-side print queue and the Windows client computer functions as a grossly overpriced LPR print server.

Comment: I am aware of Print services for Unix but dont know how to set them up properly :(. Also tried several times with google but could not achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make the machine act as a printer server but you don't want to use the software provided for making it a printer server.

Yes its possible - but you'll need to find a MSWindows server binary for [cups](http://www.cups.org/).

I recommend you just use the bundled software.

Comment: I dont want file and printer sharing on my network. This is main reason for my question.

Comment: Is there some reason you don't file and print sharing enabled? (yet still want to share printer files)?